# Fire eclipse event programmatically C#

Tags: c#, eclipse, listener

I add a menu item to eclipse in plugin, which do something where the user click on it.

I want to open eclipse in c#, and immediately do the same thing. i.e. run eclipse, and then fire the `MouseListener` of the menu item.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Very confusing and unclear what you want to do. "Open Eclipse in c#", what do you mean?

Comment: I want to run eclipse application via c# code, and then simulate the menu item event programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a C# application to simulate triggering an Eclipse menu action? As far as I know it cannot be done directly.

But there is a testing framework, [SWTbot](http://eclipse.org/swtbot/), that can run and trigger Eclipse actions and compare the results. It's a bit difficult to learn, but you have a lot of possibilities for testing. So I guess what you could do... Is to setup your C# application to run a SWTBot testcase which starts up Eclipse, triggers the menu item, and report back the results. But its not really a good idea.